# If a timed automaton always terminates, does there exist a trace with a maximum length?

Tags: automata-theory

I have a theoretical question regarding timed automata and I would like to know if someone has already given an answer to it, since that would be useful for my research. So my question is the following:

> Assume that you have a timed automaton that has an accepting state $q_f$ (that has no successors) and you know that all the traces of the configuration $(q,\delta)$ (for a location $q$ of the automaton and a clock valuation $\delta$) always terminate, that is they lead to $q_f$. Does that mean that there exists a trace of that has a maximal length (e.g the computation tree of $(q,\delta)$ has a finite depth)?

Comment: You may be interested in [Koenig's infinity lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_lemma).

Comment: Hi,  I am already aware of that, however it only applies to trees where each vertex has only a finite number of successors. In in the case of the computation tree of a timed automaton you may have an infinite number of branches.

Comment: If a state can have an infinite number of branches, then each branch could terminate but there is no upper found on trace length.

Comment: Is there a proof of your statement somewhere? Or is it what you are assuming what could happen?

Comment: I have no knowledge of the context of your question, so I can't answer for sure, but it could be that for an unbounded sequence $a_n$, there is a branch that terminates in $a_n$ steps. You decide if that is possible. Is the number of states finite?

Comment: No the states space is infinite. My question is very specific, however thanks a lot for your time spent!